# How to put labels on top of input elements in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, css, html

Is there a simple "Correct" way to move labels from the side to the top of an input element? if I disable for in lable it goes to the top but that seems like a cheat.

[image: boxes]

Comment: Are you enclosing it inside a div or some other container?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your label is not in a `.ui-field-contain` then it is styled as `block` otherwise as `inline-block`.

Comment: added a label propriety to my css to display as block. easier than having to go thru all the jQM css code.